# List of files accessed by application

Tags: files, security, process, monitoring

I want to install propertiary AMD driver but I would also like to know which files were created/changed by installer. Is there some application which can observe (probably by inotify) which files were changed by run application?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `strace` to capture exactly what the installer does when it's invoked. Something like this will capture all of its output:

```
$ strace -s 2000 -m output.log <cmd>
```

You can then look through the resulting log file, `output.log`, looking at the `open...` lines to see which files were touched.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I use following invocation:

```
strace -e trace=file programname
```

It will output only invocation of file specific function of programname.